# ccnet error with msbuild and nuget error code="MSB3073"

Tags: msbuild, nuget, cruisecontrol.net, nuget-package-restore

I've been struggling with this error for quite some time.

I've scrubbed the paths, but I've checked the paths and the sources and they are correct.  I've checked the proxy and it works.  I've run the command in a command line and it works fine, but ccnet / msbuild logs these errors.

```
    <message level="high"><![CDATA["C:\Develop\Web\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Develop\Web\MyCompany.MyProject\packages.config" -nocache -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/;http://ec2-54-201-44-121.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/nuget/"  -NonInteractive  -solutionDir "C:\Develop\Web\ "]]></message>
    <error file="WARNING" line="0" column="0" timeStamp="02/27/2014 11:40:52"><![CDATA[(403) Forbidden.]]></error>
    <error file="WARNING" line="0" column="0" timeStamp="02/27/2014 11:40:52"><![CDATA[(403) Forbidden.]]></error>
    <error file="WARNING" line="0" column="0" timeStamp="02/27/2014 11:40:52"><![CDATA[(403) Forbidden.]]></error>
    <error file="WARNING" line="0" column="0" timeStamp="02/27/2014 11:40:52"><![CDATA[(403) Forbidden.]]></error>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Installing 'MyProject.MyCompany.Common 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Installing 'MyProject.EnterpriseLibrary.4.1 1.0.1'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Installing 'MyProject.Web.Cms.Libraries 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Installing 'MyProject.MyCompany.Interactive.DataAccess 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Successfully installed 'MyProject.MyCompany.Interactive.DataAccess 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Successfully installed 'MyProject.MyCompany.Common 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Successfully installed 'MyProject.EnterpriseLibrary.4.1 1.0.1'.]]></message>
    <message level="high"><![CDATA[Successfully installed 'MyProject.Web.Cms.Libraries 1.0.0'.]]></message>
    <error code="MSB3073" file="C:\Develop\Web\.nuget\NuGet.targets" line="88" column="9" timeStamp="02/27/2014 11:41:03"><![CDATA[The command ""C:\Develop\Web\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Develop\Web\MyCompany.MyProject\packages.config" -nocache -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/;http://ec2-54-201-44-121.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/nuget/"  -NonInteractive  -solutionDir "C:\Develop\Web\ "" exited with code -1.]]></error>
  </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Log in as the IDENTIY (domain\username) that CC.NET service is running.

I had something similar with a source-control command line tool.
Once I logged in as the identity the service was using.......and ran the command line (that you say works ), I saw the error quickly.

So this is kind of an educated guess.  But I've seen something similar.

If you don't have a dedicated identity (domain\username) to run the CC.NET Service.........I'd create one.

You can also stop the service..and (temporarily) run cc.net from the command line........but again.....logged in as the identity that runs the cc.net-service.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still exists, but this made me think of something else and I can see the error in the command line now

Comment: That was the kind of the point.  To see the real error.  My svn error had nothing to do with CC.NET.  It was that I had to accept the "certificate" permanently under the identity.  But I saw the real issue.

Comment: Is it the same error? Or are you getting a slightly different report?

Comment: It was the same error after logging in with the service account.  The service account was getting blocked at the web proxy level differently.  Once able to reproduce, I was quickly able to tweak the config files until it worked.  Basically, my AWS nuget server is http and works, the htts public nuget server didn't